# Interpreting output of patch --dry-run

Tags: django, patch

I am trying to apply a patch to my copy of the django source code.  The patch comes from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13163.  When I do a dry run, I get:

```
$ patch --dry-run -p1 < ~/.../inline_edit_link.diff
>> patching file contrib/admin/options.py
>> Hunk #1 succeeded at 1284 (offset -19 lines).
>> patching file contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html
$
```

I see that the first part of the patch worked.  But I don't see anything about what happened to the second file.  Was this patch successful?  Should I apply this patch?

Comment: On my iphone I am seeing an answer, "Looks like all hunks apply with success.  You should backup before applying the patch anyway."  If this is correct, why does it specifically say that patch 1 succeeded but say nothing about patch 2?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that in the first case the succeeded message was actually a light warning:  It was telling you that the file was not exactly the same as the file used to create the patch.  It didn't find the correct material exactly where it was expected, but it found the spot 19 lines earlier in the code.  It's just letting you know so you can go have a looksee.

Your second hunk was exactly as expected so no informative statement was issued.